# Unable to install breakpoint - Wildfly remote debugging / Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, wildfly

I am suddenly getting an error while trying to remote debug a Wildfly (9.0.1) WAR web application using Eclipse.

```
Unable to install breakpoint in com.yadayada.rest.PageService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy due to missing line number attributes.  Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes.
```

I have ensured the "Add variable attributes", "Add line number", "Add source file name" options are all checked in Eclipse properties.  (Note based on several other similar StackOverflow posts, I have unchecked these, applied the changes, rebuilt the application, left eclipse, come back in, re-checked them, rebuild).

I exploded my WAR and did a javap -l on a class file (specifically the one I am trying to debug) and this showed me a a LineNumberTable and LocalVariableTable for all my methods, so I feel like the line numbers are being included.

I **seem** to be able to debug okay, but I am confused by the error.

My process to do the debugging:

```
1. I have a break point set in my code.
2. I have Wildfly started with the debug option (sh standalone.sh --debug)
3. I have a Remote Java Application defined in Eclipse and start debugging by clicking DEBUG on the debug configuration.
```

Some information that may be helpfulL

```
1. MacOS 10.14.15; Wildfly 9.0.1; Eclipse Photon 4.8.0 build 20180619-1200; Maven 3.3.3
2. To build my WAR, I am using:  mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you do 'Add line number attribute' for Eclipse in MacOS? I cannot find the way to do it.

Comment: Eclipse --> Preferences --> Java --> Compiler --> Classfile Generation.  It's the first several check box options.